# How to make label from NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, label

I just learned Python, I want to ask something..

For example, I have

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[11, 12, 13],
              [14, 16, 13],
              [17, 15, 11],
              [12, 14, 15]])
```

I want to find the label of that array

so .. in the first row the max value is 13, then the label result = 3

in the second row the max value is 16, then the label result = 2

desired results is like this

```
[3 2 1 3] or [[3]
              [2]
              [1]
              [3]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([[11, 12, 13],
              [14, 16, 13],
              [17, 15, 11],
              [12, 14, 15]])

>>> np.argmax(a, axis=1) + 1

array([3, 2, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

[`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) gives the indices of the max values in the specified axis.
So,

```
>>> np.argmax(a, axis=1)
array([2, 1, 0, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Then all you need to do is add `1` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
d=[]
for lst in a:
    d.append(lst.index(max(lst))+1)
print(d)
```

---

output

```
[3, 2, 1, 3]
```

---

```
d=[]
for lst in a:
    d.append([lst.index(max(lst))+1])
print(d)
```

---

output

```
[[3], [2], [1], [3]]
```